# Why compression doesn't work in iText7 from Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying to convert several images to PDF file using iText7 (version 8.0.3) from Android (Kotlin). It works great but even if I set compression the resulting file always has the same size. In other words, compression doesn't work. I don't understand why. My document contains only images.

```
    fun convertUrisToPdf() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    val image = Image(ImageDataFactory.create(fileHolder.imagePathList[0]))
                    val pdfFilePath = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "${filename.value}.pdf")
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath)
                    val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(outputStream, WriterProperties().setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION))
                    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
                    val eventHandler = PageRotationEventHandler()
                    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler)
                    eventHandler.setRotation(orientation.value)
                    val document = Document(pdfDocument, getPageSize(image))
                    setMarginsToTheDocument(document)
                    createPages(document, pdfDocument)
                    document.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "convertUrisToPdf: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private fun createPages(document: Document, pdfDocument: PdfDocument) {
        fileHolder.imagePathList.forEach { uri ->
            val image = Image(ImageDataFactory.create(uri))
            setImageSize(image)
            pdfDocument.addNewPage(getPageSize(image))
            document.add(image)
        }
    }
```

Here is my code. I tried to set compression directly to pdfWriter (pdfWriter.compressionLevel = 9, for example). The value applyed, I see it when I add logs. But file size is the same.

Comment: What kind of image are you starting with? Are they already compressed or not? E.g. jpg images compression usually won't change when embedding them in PDFs (unless the PDF creation software reduces their resolution or quality for extra compression which iText does not do).

Comment: @mkl the images are from gallery on my phone. I think all of them are Jpg... Thanks for your answer, I'll try to add some png images or other types for testing compression.

Comment: png images can also be well compressed. Putting images into pdfs simply is no good way to compress them. You can better compress them using dedicated image libraries and explicitly change resolutions and quality settings. Thereafter you can still put them into a pdf.

Comment: Have you tried the Native PDFDocument class instead of iText? as you can create PDF with that and add images to it via the canvas.

Comment: I would assume that the compression argument is only about the whole-file compression which uses LZW/ZIP. It doesn't affect the image compression/encoding with can be JPEG or something like PNG. So check the code where you add the image into your PDF file, there should be a way to specify the compression and the compression ratio in case of JPEG.